# "Sorry Something went wrong" when I modify view in SharePoint 2013 Assets Library!

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list-view

I am trying to simply modify my assets library view in SharePoint 2013 which we upgraded 3 weeks ago. when I click on modify view the  massage appear:
"Sorry Something went wrong" an unexpected error has been occurred.
I thought it is only for thumbnail view and I changed to  all assets but nothing has changed.
I really cannot understand the  problem, I tried to search for features but everything were normal. 
it is a win 7 server 2012 and SharePoint 2013.
I appreciate for  any experience.

Comment: Are you sure all the fields used in the view are still present and not uninstalled?

Comment: Could you provide related log entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicly it say delete the site assets library en press the title, logo and description link Again.

http://johnmhester.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/error-changing-a-site-title-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: How does it address the issue in question? Link you've provided describes "Error changing a site title", not editing views in Site Assets.

Comment: I think it might be correct in different cases.I marked as answer because when I deleted the web part in the library or even added one in another page it worked! I could modify the view! but not in the library itself! (it is silly) but I will look for the root of these kind of unknown error!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac, you can use the Site Content Structure to move the files. Here are the steps for your reference:

1. Go to your team site.

   2. Click the gear in the upper right, select Site settings and click the Site collection features in the Site collection Administration section.
   3. Activate the SharePoint Server Publishing infrastructure feature.
   4. Back to the Site settings and click the Content and structure in the Site Administration section.
   5. Click the previous picture library in the left panel.
   6. Select the items that you want to move and then click the Actions > Move… to move the items to the new picture library.

Comment: Thanks for answer but my problem was modifying the view. but I believe that I can use your solution in different cases and it is really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found the cause.  You have to have the Site Collection Feature "Video and Rich Media" enabled before you create the Asset Library.  Else, you will not be able to edit the views.  Once I enabled the feature, recreated the Asset Library, all the views worked perfectly.

Comment: You are right but the problem was migration so the assets libraries were full and not possible to recreate them. but thanks for your attention....